# multi level nested grid for win & web apps?

Tags: asp.net

is there any free open source multi level nested grid developed using c# for windows and web apps . i need a grid which can display parent child relation ship at nth level with plus minus sign. if is available then please give me the url.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find out nested grid at below mentioned url.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Hierarchical_Grid_View.aspx

Hope it will help.